# Poisson mixed model with constant weights (glmer)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, poisson-regression, weights

I have count data $Y_{i}$ associated with dates $d_{i}$ for $i\in\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$. I would like to model $Y_{i}$ in terms of a population "baseline" count and a date-specific effect. I am therefore considering Poisson regression with a global intercept and a random effect for each date, so that the model is

$$
\log\left(\mathrm{E}\left[Y_{i}|b_{i}\right]\right)=\mathbf{X}_{i}^{\mathsf{T}}\boldsymbol{\beta}+\mathbf{Z}_{i}^{\mathsf{T}}\mathbf{b}_{i}=\beta+b_{i},\quad b_{i}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right).
$$

(I am aware that including a random effect for each observation can be used in Poisson regression to model overdispersion, e.g., observation-level random effects as described [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#fitting-models-with-overdispersion). In this case, I would like to use a mixed-effects model to take advantage of shrinkage, as described below. In addition, $n$ is large and including a dummy variable for each $d_{i}$ is intractable.)

This model can be fit with `lme4::glmer()` by

```r
glmer(y ~ (1 | date), data = data, family = poisson)
```

I am also interested in controlling the shrinkage, which can be done with the `weights`. Let $w>0$ be the (constant) weight for each observation, so that the call becomes

```r
glmer(y ~ (1 | date), data = data, family = poisson, weights = rep(w, nrow(data)))
```

I am interested in how $w$ affects both the degree of shrinkage and the individual predictions $\hat{Y}_{i}$. Is there an expression for shrinkage in terms of $w$? I am thinking of an analog to the decomposition in section 8.6 of [*Applied Longitudinal Analysis*](https://content.sph.harvard.edu/fitzmaur/ala2e/) by Fitzmaurice, Laird, and Ware, i.e.,

$$
\hat{Y}_{i}=\left(\hat{\mathbf{R}}_{i}\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}_{i}^{-1}\right)\mathbf{X}_{i}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}+\left(\mathbf{I}_{n_{i}}-\hat{\mathbf{R}}_{i}\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}_{i}^{-1}\right)Y_{i},
$$

where $\hat{\mathbf{R}}_{i}$ is the estimated covariance matrix of the residuals for the $i\text{th}$ subject and $\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}_{i}^{-1}$ is the inverse of the estimated covariance matrix of the observations for the $i\text{th}$ subject.

The example above is for a linear mixed effects model, and is also problematic in my case because I have a single observation for each $d_{i}$, so that the subject-specific covariances are undefined. With this in mind, is there a way to modify the expression for the predictions from the unweighted model $\hat{Y}_{i}=\exp\left(\hat{\beta}+\hat{b}_{i}\right)$ to include $w$?